# cant upload an ssh key to github

Tags: github

In GitHub I am supposed to go to Account Setting, then click on SSH keys, and there I should have some way to add an SSH Key. The instructions at http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/ say: "click "Add SSH Key". But that link does not exist.  Instead I get the following:

> On Sunday March 4, 2012 a security vulnerability related to SSH keys
>   (public keys) was discovered. For your protection and to prevent
>   unauthorized access we have disabled your public keys until you
>   approve them.
>
> Need help verifying fingerprints?

along with Accept and Reject buttons next to ssh keys I have uploaded but not verified since the exploit was found.  I do not want to accept or reject any of these other ssh keys at this point. All I want is to add a new SSH Key.  How do I do it?

Many thanks!

Comment: Accept or reject them (why not? that won't hurt anything), then try uploading a new key.

Comment: Thanks! @icyrock.com is that what is blocking me? do you, on your account see that link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After accepting/rejecting all the existing ssh keys the link was visible again in my account.